# The method or operation is not implemented: Reset all sessions in my application

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

I want to reset all session in my web app hosted on IIS version 10. I am using this code and added reference of `Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll` version 7.0 from nuget:

```
   public void RecycleAppPool()
    {
        using (ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager())
        {
            SiteCollection sites = iisManager.Sites;
            foreach (Site site in sites)
            {
            if (site.Name == stingEnvironment.ApplicationHost.GetSiteName())
                {
                    **iisManager.ApplicationPools[site.Applications["/"].ApplicationPoolName].Recycle();**
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but the above line raises an exception:

> The method or operation is not implemented.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please specify the line where the exception occurs

Comment: iisManager.ApplicationPools[site.Applications["/"].ApplicationPoolName].Recycle();

Comment: Have you included all necessary assemblies and usings? And which IIS version do you use?

Comment: I am added Microsoft.Web.Administration and System.Web.Hosting

Comment: Again, which IIS version do you use?

Comment: IIS version is 10.0

Comment: As usual with debugging, I'd try breaking it down first. `var application = site.Applications["/"];`, check if application is defined. `var poolName = application.ApplicationPoolName`, check if poolName is correct. `var pool = iisManager.ApplicationPools[poolName];`, check if pool is correct. `pool.Recycle();` see if the error occurs on this line still. It might be one of the property accessors that is throwing, but you might not know. You could also look at the stack the exception shows.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I was testing the code in Visual Studio, using IIS Express. Once I deployed the code into an IIS web site it worked.